# setText in fragment from another activity not related with fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i wanna set `textView` in fragment from another activity which this activity is not `MainActivity` has fragment `transaction` ..

already tried some method from the other related article which related with my problem, but got an error..

here's my method inside fragment to `recieve` from another activity

Fragment A

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating view layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, container, false);

        //Put Data to id fragment
        valueName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.valueNameNav);
        valueStatus = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.valueStatusNav);

    }

    public void setText(String name, String status){

            valueName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.valueNameNav);
            valueName.setText(name);
            valueStatus = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.valueStatusNav);
            valueStatus.setText(status);
    }
}
```

and this is how i call `setText` method in fragment from activity

```
String editValueName= editName.getText().toString();
String lastStatus = valueStatus.getText().toString();

FragmentA mFragment = (FragmentA )
     getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_A);

mFragment.setText(editValueName, lastStatus);
```

but got an error like this

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.example.study.fragment.fragmentA.setText(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

100% sure there's a data string on string `getText`

Comment: you can not settext for a view of another activity ,you have to be in that activity to set the text ,you can use intent to pass a string from one activity to another

Comment: You can not access fragment that is not part of that activity. But if you really want to perform such task. Use should `BroadcastReceiver`.
And if your fragment is attached to the activity you should Interfaces to this work.

Comment: Here fragment is null (or) fragment is not in added state. Make sure your fragment is already added.

Comment: oh thank you, my case is i've an activity and this activity is for update Name, after it was saved i want all fragment is change to new value of name. there's 1 fragment didn't change anything. i want to put this value into it.. have you recommend related article to solve my problem?

Comment: try this link for more information on how to interact with fragments from activity
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Set the tag and access your fragment with TAG

Comment: `private static String TAG = Fragment_A.class.getSimpleName();` this one did you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a FrameLayout in your activity with id `container` with height width to MATCH_PARENT
Then add fragment in your activity like this

```
FragmentA newFragment = new FragmentA ();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment).commit();
```

and than set your text

```
String editValueName= editName.getText().toString();
String lastStatus = valueStatus.getText().toString();
newFragment .setText(editValueName, lastStatus);
```

Comment: that fragment was attached on `MainActivity` and the data i want to pass to fragment_A is from `UpdateActivity`

Comment: `Wrong 2nd argument type: Found 'com.example.study.fragment.fragmentA, required 'android.app.fragment' replace (int, android.app.fragment) in fragment transaction to (int, com.example.study.fragment.fragmentA)` show this error on `ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment).commit();` the `newFragment` is the problem

Comment: your need to make `import android.app.Fragment` instead of this `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in imports

Answer (score 2):

You can useing store SharedPreferences for save your string and load it in every where.Of course, if you like to change your code.

Comment: already tried, but still no update here .. the data is from server, on server is updated, on fragment_B/C/D is updated.. only fragment_A not updated. but `sharedPreferences` is not very recommeded

Answer (score 2):

No need to findView in setText method you should do in this way and it will work

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

TextView valueName,valueStatus ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflating view layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, container, false);

    //Put Data to id fragment
    valueName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.valueNameNav);
    valueStatus = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.valueStatusNav);

 return layout;
}

public void setText(String name, String status){

        valueName.setText(name);
        valueStatus.setText(status);
}
```

}

Comment: still null object, should i checked the value of string?? i am pretty sure cause on the other fragment was updated. only fragment_A is not `recieve` an update from `UpdateActivity`

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this and make sure your fragment is attached with activity.

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grupos);

    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        fragment = new FragmentA();
        fragment.setTag(R.id.myfragmentId);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
    else
    {
        if(fragment == null)
        {
            fragment = (FragmentA) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(R.id.myfragmentId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it was attached. let me know, which activity to put in those code?? my fragment was attached in `MainActivity` .. and i the string is from `UpdateActivity` .. is that possible?